# how to select and sum the values of specific rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to sum the values of particular rows from MySQL like if my table contains 2 columns id and name having values

```
|id |name   |
|1  |yatin  |
|2  |max    |
|3  |josh   |
|4  |bob    |
|5  |mary   |
|6  |jane   |
```

and i want to select the the rows from name max to mary and sum their id so that i will get like
|value  |
|14 |

Comment: why only rows 4-8?  please edit your post with your current query or any information about the table you are querying

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT SUM(a.id) total 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN my_table x 
    ON x.id <= a.id 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id >= a.id 
 WHERE x.name = 'max' 
   AND y.name = 'mary';
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.! i got the answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(id) FROM yourtable WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 8;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(id) FROM yourtable WHERE id > 3 AND id < 9;
```

etc...

Comment: Thank you..! but how can i do it on varchar column

Comment: SUM(CAST(id AS INTEGER))

Comment: can you write full query taking example of varchar name column

Comment: Why didn't you ask the comment with the correct column name and type. I don't think your ID column is a varchar... but anyway...

Comment: lets say i have 2 column id(int) and name(varchar) having values  1)Andrew, 2)Bob, 3)Jimmy, 4)Lucian, 5)Yatin and if i want to add the values of id between name bob and lucian... how can i do it?

Comment: i want to add those values

Comment: @YatinGaikwad it is also possible to [compare two `varchar`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) column. Rewrite where clause as follows `WHERE name >= 'bob AND name <= 'lucian';`

Comment: i tried it bt it then gives me names whose initials are greater than b and less than l

Comment: There are more optimized queries, but a simple one to understand that you are doing it wrong is: select SUM(id) from table where id between (select id from table where name = 'x') and (select id from table where name = 'y'). I hope you understand the correct logic...

Comment: thanx @lucian i got the logic